# As i click on the save button :- it displays the message " the app is not responding"

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-layout, import

I created this project to save the data entered in the table in the form of sq lite . But whenever i click on the save button :- it displays the message " the app is not responding". so, how to resolve it.

so the coding in main class is :-

```
package phoenixstudio.ramasales;

 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.Spinner;
 import android.widget.Toast;

public class ADD_BILL extends AppCompatActivity {

Spinner spinner;
Spinner spinner2;
Spinner spinner3;
Spinner spinner4;
Spinner spinner5;
Spinner spinner6;
Spinner spinner7;
Spinner spinner8;
Spinner spinner9;
Spinner spinner10;


ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>adapter;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>adapter2;

databasehelper myDB;
Button button5;
EditText editText2;
EditText editText3;
EditText editText4;
EditText editText5;
EditText editText6;
EditText editText7;
EditText editText8;
EditText editText10;
EditText editText11;
EditText editText12;
EditText editText13;
EditText editText14;
EditText editText15;
EditText editText16;
EditText editText17;
EditText editText18;
EditText editText19;
EditText editText20;
EditText editText21;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add__bill);
    spinner =(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    spinner3=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    spinner4=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
    spinner5=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner5);
    spinner6=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner6);
    spinner7=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner7);
    spinner8=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner8);
    spinner9=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner9);
    spinner10=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner10);

    button5=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    editText2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    editText3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    editText4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    editText5=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    editText6=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    editText7=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText7);
    editText8=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText8);
    editText10=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText10);
    editText11=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText11);
    editText12=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText12);
    editText13=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText13);
    editText14=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText14);
    editText15=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText15);
    editText16=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText16);
    editText17=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText17);
    editText18=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText18);
    editText19=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText19);
    editText20=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText20);
    editText21=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText21);





    adapter =ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.product,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    adapter2 =ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.beat,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner3.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner4.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner5.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner6.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner7.setAdapter(adapter2);
    spinner8.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner9.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner10.setAdapter(adapter);

    myDB = new databasehelper(this);
    AddData();

}
public  void AddData(){
    button5.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   boolean isInserted = myDB.inserdata(spinner7.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                            editText2.getText().toString(),
                            spinner.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                            editText3.getText().toString(),
                            editText10.getText().toString(),
                            spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                            editText4.getText().toString(),
                            editText11.getText().toString(),
                            spinner3.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                            editText5.getText().toString(),
                            editText12.getText().toString(),
                            spinner4.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                            editText6.getText().toString(),
                            editText13.getText().toString(),
                            spinner5.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                            editText7.getText().toString(),
                            editText14.getText().toString(),
                            spinner6.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                            editText8.getText().toString(),
                            editText15.getText().toString(),
                            spinner8.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                            editText16.getText().toString(),
                            editText17.getText().toString(),
                            spinner9.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                            editText18.getText().toString(),
                            editText19.getText().toString());
                    if (isInserted=true)
                        Toast.makeText(ADD_BILL.this,"DATA INSERTED",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    else
                    Toast.makeText(ADD_BILL.this,"DATA NOT INSERTED",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }





            }






    );

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_add__bill, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

and the coding in database helper class is :-

```
package phoenixstudio.ramasales;

 import android.content.ContentValues;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
```

/**
     * Created by win-7 on 23/03/2016.
     */
    public class databasehelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "bill";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "order";
public static final String COL_1 = "beat";
public static final String COL_2 = "NAME";
public static final String COL_3 = "product";
public static final String COL_4 = "scheme";
public static final String COL_5 = "quantity";
public static final String COL_6 = "product2";
public static final String COL_7 = "scheme2";
public static final String COL_8 = "quantity2";
public static final String COL_9 = "product3";
public static final String COL_10 = "scheme3";
public static final String COL_11= "quantity3";
public static final String COL_12= "product4";
public static final String COL_13= "scheme4";
public static final String COL_14= "quantity4";
public static final String COL_15= "product5";
public static final String COL_16= "scheme5";
public static final String COL_17= "quantity5";
public static final String COL_18= "product6";
public static final String COL_19= "scheme6";
public static final String COL_20= "quantity6";
public static final String COL_21= "product7";
public static final String COL_22= "scheme7";
public static final String COL_23= "quantity7";
public static final String COL_24= "product8";
public static final String COL_25= "scheme8";
public static final String COL_26= "quantity8";

public databasehelper(Context context) {

    super(context,DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table" + TABLE_NAME + "(beat TEXT + NAME TEXT + product TEXT + scheme TEXT + quantity INTEGER+product2 TEXT + scheme2 TEXT + quantity2 INTEGER+product3 TEXT + scheme3 TEXT + quantity3 INTEGER+product4 TEXT + scheme4 TEXT + quantity4 INTEGER+product5 TEXT + scheme5 TEXT + quantity5 INTEGER+product6 TEXT + scheme6 TEXT + quantity6 INTEGER+product7 TEXT + scheme7 TEXT + quantity7 INTEGER+product8 TEXT + scheme8 TEXT + quantity8 INTEGER)");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXITS " + TABLE_NAME );
    onCreate(db);

}

public boolean inserdata(String beat1, String name , String product , String scheme, String quantity,String product2 , String scheme2, String quantity2,String product3 , String scheme3, String quantity3,String product4 , String scheme4, String quantity4,String product5 , String scheme5, String quantity5,String product6 , String scheme6, String quantity6,String product7 , String scheme7, String quantity7,String product8 , String scheme8, String quantity8){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_1 ,beat1);
    contentValues.put(COL_2 ,name);
    contentValues.put(COL_3 ,product);
    contentValues.put(COL_4 ,scheme);
    contentValues.put(COL_5 ,quantity);
    contentValues.put(COL_6 ,product2);
    contentValues.put(COL_7 ,scheme2);
    contentValues.put(COL_8 ,quantity2);
    contentValues.put(COL_9 ,product3);
    contentValues.put(COL_10 ,scheme3);
    contentValues.put(COL_11 ,quantity3);
    contentValues.put(COL_12 ,product4);
    contentValues.put(COL_13 ,scheme4);
    contentValues.put(COL_14 ,quantity4);
    contentValues.put(COL_15 ,product5);
    contentValues.put(COL_16 ,scheme5);
    contentValues.put(COL_17 ,quantity5);
    contentValues.put(COL_18 ,product6);
    contentValues.put(COL_19 ,scheme6);
    contentValues.put(COL_20 ,quantity6);
    contentValues.put(COL_21 ,product7);
    contentValues.put(COL_22 ,scheme7);
    contentValues.put(COL_23 ,quantity7);
    contentValues.put(COL_24 ,product8);
    contentValues.put(COL_25 ,scheme8);
    contentValues.put(COL_26 ,quantity8);
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);



    return false;
}
```

}

and the coding in th layout is :-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="phoenixstudio.ramasales.ADD_BILL">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="@string/market_beat"
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_column="0" />

                <Spinner
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/spinner7"
                    android:layout_column="1" />
           </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="@string/shop_name"
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_column="0" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/editText2"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:inputType="none" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="@string/product"
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_column="0" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="@string/scheme"
                    android:id="@+id/textView8"
                    android:layout_column="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="@string/quantity"
                    android:id="@+id/textView9"
                    android:layout_column="2" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <Spinner
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/spinner"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/editText3"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:inputType="none" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:id="@+id/editText10"
                    android:layout_column="2" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <Spinner
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
                    android:layout_column="0" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/editText4"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:inputType="none" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:id="@+id/editText11"
                    android:layout_column="2" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <Spinner
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/spinner3"
                    android:layout_column="0" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/editText5"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:inputType="none" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:id="@+id/editText12"
                    android:layout_column="2" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <Spinner
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/spinner4"
                    android:layout_column="0" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/editText6"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:inputType="none" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:id="@+id/editText13"
                    android:layout_column="2" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <Spinner
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/spinner5"
                    android:layout_column="0" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/editText7"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:inputType="none" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:id="@+id/editText14"
                    android:layout_column="2" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <Spinner
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/spinner6"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/editText8"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:inputType="none" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:id="@+id/editText15"
                    android:layout_column="2" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <Spinner
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/spinner8"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/editText16"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:inputType="none" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:id="@+id/editText17"
                    android:layout_column="2" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <Spinner
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/spinner9"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/editText18"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:inputType="none" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:id="@+id/editText19"
                    android:layout_column="2" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <Spinner
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/spinner10"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/editText20"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:inputType="none" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:id="@+id/editText21"
                    android:layout_column="2" />
            </TableRow>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="500dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="@string/save"
                android:id="@+id/button5" />
        </TableLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

so kindly tell
how to avoid that error.
thanx in advance .

the logcat is :-

**03-28 17:06:30.922    5910-5941/phoenixstudio.ramasales E/Surface﹕ getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xabfb64f0
03-28 17:06:30.931    5910-5941/phoenixstudio.ramasales D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ endAllStagingAnimators on 0xa2b44680 (ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView) with handle 0xa2f11c20
03-28 17:06:34.163    5910-5919/phoenixstudio.ramasales W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 7.679ms
03-28 17:06:41.236    5910-5919/phoenixstudio.ramasales W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 18.376ms
03-28 17:06:42.309    5910-5923/phoenixstudio.ramasales I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 8871(574KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 1631KB/2MB, paused 24.288ms total 129.703ms
03-28 17:06:44.136    5910-5910/phoenixstudio.ramasales E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near "TABLEPRODUCT_table": syntax error
03-28 17:06:44.151    5910-5910/phoenixstudio.ramasales D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    --------- beginning of crash
03-28 17:06:44.153    5910-5910/phoenixstudio.ramasales E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: phoenixstudio.ramasales, PID: 5910
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEPRODUCT_table": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEPRODUCT_table(Market_Beat TEXT, Shop_Name TEXT,product TEXT,scheme TEXT, quantity INTEGER )
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1674)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1605)
            at phoenixstudio.ramasales.databasehelper.onCreate(databasehelper.java:30)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
            at phoenixstudio.ramasales.databasehelper.insertData(databasehelper.java:44)
            at phoenixstudio.ramasales.Take_order$1.onClick(Take_order.java:70)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
03-28 17:06:46.704    5910-5919/phoenixstudio.ramasales W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 16.075ms**

Comment: Have a look at the docs here: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html

Comment: okhay ...wait @Ritesh

Comment: I have posted the logcat . so kindly have a look at it . and tell me , where i am going wrong .thankyou.  @Ritesh

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEPRODUCT_table": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEPRODUCT_table(Market_Beat TEXT, Shop_Name TEXT,product TEXT,scheme TEXT, quantity INTEGER ) at..... It clearly says there is a syntax error in Create statement.

Comment: SO , can u please tell the error and tell how to solve it .     i hav mentioned all the coding.@Ritesh